# How much days left from today to given date

Tags: python

I have a date - 2015.05.20

What is the best way to calculate using python how much days left from today till this date?

```
from datetime import *
today = date.today()
future = date(2015,05,20)
???
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
future = datetime.date(2019,9,20)
diff = future - today
print (diff.days)
```

`diff` is a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object.

Comment: I love that this question and reply are so old, the future is actually 3 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

subtract them.

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> today = date.today()
>>> future = date(2015,05,20)
>>> str(future - today)
'1326 days, 0:00:00'
>>> (future - today).days
1326
```

Comment: Then use str(future - today).split('.')[0] to remove the microseconds which is typically undesired for a human-friendly display.