# Need assistance solving this issue in a function

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have an assignment in my computer science class and need help fixing a function but I have no clue what's wrong! The function is called 'days_left'. This function takes in three variables, Day, Month, and Year. It is supposed to output how many total days are left in that year. I have tried my best but cannot figure it out! Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here's the script:

```py
def leap_year(year):
    if (year % 4) == 0:
        if (year % 100) == 0:
            if (year % 400) == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False
 
 
def number_of_days(month, year):
    days31 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
    days30 = [4, 6, 9, 11]
    if month in days31:
        return 31
    elif month in days30:
        return 30
    else:
        if not leap_year(year):
            return 28
        else:
            return 29
 

def days_left(month, day, year):
    days = 0
    for i in range(1, month):
        days += number_of_days(i, year)
    days += day
    for x in range(year):
        if leap_year(year):
            return 366 - days
        else:
            return 365 - days

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Please enter a date: \n")
 
    d = int(input("Day: "))
    m = int(input("Month: "))
    y = int(input("Year: "))
 
    print("\nMenu:")
    print("1) Calculate the number of days in the given month.")
    print("2) Calculate the number of days left in the given year.")
    selection = int(input())
 
    if selection == 1:
        print(number_of_days(m, y))
    elif selection == 2:
        print(days_left(d, m, y))
    else:
        print('')
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `datetime` module?

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what is the problem with your attempt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much days left from today to given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628036/how-much-days-left-from-today-to-given-date)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sadly no. I have to rely on math solely.

Comment: @mkrieger1 When I run the script and enter in the day, month and year, everything runs fine except for that function. I don't know why but when I call the function to determine how many days are left in the inputted year it brings back a negative number. Ex: When I enter this: 'Days: 31, Month 12, Year: 2020' it returns -534! I can't tell if its the counting variable or something else!

Comment: How are you going to calculate this if you have no computer?

Comment: What do you mean 'No computer'?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. You actually have a decent approach in the code. However, consider what happens in `for x in range(year)`. Why do you use a loop here?

Comment: Oh, that's not going to solve the problem either. I guess you will have to read this, then: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What is the order of the parameters of the `days_left` function and in what order are you passing the arguments to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def days_left(day, month, year):
```

It should be 'day, month' instead 'month, day' since you are calling function with `days_left(d, m, y)`